# Binding a variable inside a service to html template in an Angular App

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an standard `Angular.js` App. I have a `service` like this:

```
app.service("myService",function(){
   this.variable = "world";
});
```

In my `controller`s I can use this `service` like this:

```
app.controller("loginCtrl",function($scope,myService){
    $scope.value = myService.variable; // this works
});
```

But my problem is that I cant access to `service` values inside my HTML template:

```
<h1>hello {{myService.variable}}</h1> //this doesn't work
```

If I store `service` variable in a temp variable inside my `controller`, I can use that temp inside the template but i don't like this method. is there any proper way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your scope variable is what angular will use to bind to your view. Your view does not have access to your services as they are not part of your scope.

The controllers purpose if to bring all your services together and provide that data to your view/scope.

You generally don't expose your services directly to your scope. They usually provide generic single reuseable pieces of logic. This makes them greatly re-usable and easily testable. However you could data bind directly to them by

`$scope.myService = myService`;

However i would personally avoid this like the plague as a service is used through the entirety of your app, changes your view makes to the service will be reflected throughout your application. This will make your service un-trustable is structure and most likely useless.

I created a fiddle showing : http://jsfiddle.net/5g3tnq17/

```
var app = angular.module('test', [])
.controller('testController', function($scope, testService){
    //When you modify $scope.testService
    $scope.testService = testService;
})
.service('testService', function(){
    this.prop = 'hi';   
})
.directive('testDirective', function(testService){
   return {
    type: 'EA',
    template: '<button ng-click="get()">get service value</button>{{serviceValue}}',
    link: function($scope, elem, sttr){
        //Test service will also be modified anywhere else you use it
        $scope.get = function(){
            $scope.serviceValue = testService.prop;   
        }

        $scope.get();
    }
   } 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To access it in your html you need to bind it to your controller and then use `$scope` in your html like this.

**Service**

```
app.service("myService",function(){
  this.variable = "world";
});
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller("loginCtrl",function($scope,myService){
  $scope.value = myService.variable;
});
```

**HTML**

```
<h1>hello {{value}}</h1>
```

You never inject your services in your HTML, only in your controller.

Comment: thanks. as i say, i know this, but i want to know is there any other way? for example direct access to service variables from html

Comment: I missread. but no, I don't belive there is, at least not in a way that would be considered good practice. why do you want direct access?

Comment: each controllers in my app binded to its html, and there is a common variables that i use them via services in each controller and that variables changes the UI(binded to UI).

Comment: You do not instantiate services in your controllers. They are singletons, each injection (controller, directive etc) gets the same instance. Factories return a new instance to each injection, however it instantiates it itself, not the thing requesting it. Unless you expose a data object that requires instantiate after this that is.

Comment: ok right I see, so whats it called when you use a service in a controller?

Comment: Its just injected in. Its dependency injection. Angular will instantiate your service upon the first time it was asked for. It will then use that for everything else. Thas why you can use the `this` keyword to define your service method and props if you wish. `.service('test', function() { this.prop = 'eyup'; });`